# Auto Layout - Vertical spacing

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I'm Ctrl dragging from one UILabel to another to set a vertical spacing and I get the following dialog:

[image: Auto Layout vertical spacing]

1. What does this dialog mean?
2. How do I set a vertical spacing between the 2 UILabels using this dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you already have created a vertical spacing constraint. That's what the dot (•) next to Vertical Spacing means.

If you were starting from scratch, you would select Vertical Spacing. That would create a constraint which maintains the current vertical spacing between the labels as they are laid out on the canvas. You could then select that constraint and modify it, if you want. You can find the constraint in the document outline or you can look at the Size inspector for one of the affected views.

In general, that window lets you create one or more constraints based on the current layout of the designated views. Clicking on one of the items creates that one constraint. Shift-clicking on an item selects it and leaves the panel up so you can select more. When you've selected all that you want, click outside of the panel to create all the specified constraints.

Choosing "Left" creates a constraint relating the left (or leading) side of the views, with a constant for their current distance. Similar for "Center X" and "Right", except relating different attributes of the views.

Equal Widths creates a constraint relating the widths of the views, with a constant for the current difference in their widths. Similar for Equal Heights. Aspect Ratio creates a constraint relating the width of one to the height of the other (it makes most sense when you create a constraint from a view to itself).